# Populate vector down or up with unique element value (like na.locf)

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with each column containing one flag from the set {-1,1}, all the rest of the values are set to zero.  I want to fill up or down the rest of the column entries with a value corresponding to that flag value. for example, given a vector to represent 1 column, I have

```
v <- rep(0,15) 
v[12] <- 1

#I'd want a function that is something like: 
f <- function(v,flag){ 
for(i in 2:length(v)){ if(v[i-1]==flag) v[i] <- flag else v[i]<-v[i]}
v
}

> v
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
> f(v,1)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

The example works fine for filling forward some v and a flag 1. I'd also want to be able to fill backwards with 1 based on a -1 flag.  The obvious solution that comes to mind is na.locf, except I can't get it to work with a 1 in the middle and filling forward and backwards. Even if I populate the 0 elements with NA, it will still not partially fill up or down based on a flag.

Are there any simple and fast vectorized functions that could do this with a matrix or zoo object populated with all zeros, except where there is one element with 1 or -1 in each column, telling it to fill down or up with 1s depending on the value?

edit: thinking about it a bit more, I came up with a possible solution, that along with an illustration, (hopefully) makes it more clear what I want.
Also, the overall goal is to create a mask for Additions/Deletions to a fund index, by date, that fill forwards for additions (+1) and fill backwards for removals (-1). Also, why I thought of na.locf right away. Still not sure if this is the best approach for this block, though. Any thoughts appreciated.

```
#generate random matrix of flags
v.mtx <- matrix(0,15,10)
for(i in 1:10){
v.mtx[sample(1:15,1),i] <- sample(c(-1,1),1)
}

fill.flag <- function(v) {
if(any(-1 %in% v)) {v[1:which(v!=0)] <- 1}
else
if(any(1 %in% v)) {v[which(v!=0):length(v)] <- 1}
v
}

> v.mtx
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0   -1    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    -1
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   -1     0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[13,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[15,]    1   -1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
> apply(v.mtx,2,fill.flag)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     1
 [2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     1
 [3,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     1
 [4,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     1
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     1
 [6,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
 [7,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    1     1
 [8,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1     1
 [9,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1     1
[10,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1     0
[11,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    0     0
[12,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    0     0
[13,]    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0     0
[14,]    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0     0
[15,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0     0
```

Comment: If your input is a vector of all zeros and ones as in the question then `cummax(x)` will replace everything from the first 1 onwards with 1.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Added more information to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

As @G. Grothendieck commented, you can try `cummax` and `cummin`, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(x){
  if(sum(x) == 1){
    return(cummax(x))
  }else{
    return(rev(cummin(rev(x)))* -1)
  }
}

#apply as usual
apply(v.mtx, 2, f1)
```